# Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx, Gunicorn, Django - how to keep the .env file secure

Tags: django, security, ubuntu, gunicorn

I'm using [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) for using separate .env files that store sensitive data. In the case of the server being hacked, the file would be accessible to the intruder. Also, from what I read on [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167684/using-ex-ubuntu-or-windows-can-i-see-the-memory-of-a-process-that-i-am-runnin), any intruder that manages to hack into the app owner account or root has access to the process memory.

What is the most secure option for keeping the .env file secure in this enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

If the server has been compromised then the intruder can access almost anything. You can load you environment variables from the cloud service. Here is an article on [Medium](https://engineering.instawork.com/django-settings-in-the-cloud-aa3fc547a2b4) that you can follow. Also there is an app on Github [python-awsenviron](https://github.com/douglasfarinelli/python-awsenviron).